# User level threads vs Kernel level threads

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, operating-system

I'm aware that User Level threads are created on the User Mode( no privileges) and Kernel threads are created in the Kernel Mode( privileged).
I am also aware that Processor threads are hardware threads that operate on Kernel Threads( I hope I am correct by putting it in this way)

Here is my confusion:-

1. User Level threads are not recognized by the OS as they are created, maintained and destroyed on the User Level. The OS doesn't see a multithreaded process from the User Mode as being multithreaded. It treats it as a single threaded process. Therefore, this program cannot take advantage of Multiprocessing, I guess it cannot take advantage of hyperthreading as well since it appears as single threaded in the OS.
   So what's the use of Multithreading in this case? I mean the computation time will still be the same‍♂️.
2. The last question is, do  POSIX thread API and OPenMP create user level threads or Kernel threads?
   I know what both libraries are, please don't explain about that.

If none creates Kernel threads then how do we create a multithreaded program that takes advantage of multiprocessing?

Answer (score 0):

Pure user level threads are (as you pointed out) not a lot of use because they don't allow you to exploit the processing capability of multiple cores within a process.

The flip-side is that pure kernel level threads will typically incur substantial overheads when switch between threads.  (There are things that you can do to deal with that, but ... that's another topic.)  But the upshot is that the overheads make it inefficient to preform small tasks (units of work) using kernel level threads.

Another alternative to both is a hybrid of user level and kernel level threads.  For example, suppose:

- each process has one kernel level thread for each physical core,
- each kernel level thread can switch between a bunch of user level threads and,
- switching between a user level threads is handled by a scheduler in user space.

The Java Loom project is developing a new threading model (roughly) along those lines.  Classic Java threads are still kernel level threads.  New virtual threads are user level threads.  A Java program gets to choose whether it uses classic or virtual threads ... or both.

There is a lot of material on Loom on the web; e.g.

- https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/java-loom-virtual-threads-platform-threads
- https://www.infoq.com/news/2022/05/virtual-threads-for-jdk19/
- https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/loom/Main

Loom is likely to be part of the next Java release: Java 19.

---

I'm pretty sure that (C / C++) POSIX threads are kernel level.  I don't know about OpenMPI threads, but I'd expect they are kernel level too.  (They wouldn't be fit for purpose as pure user level threads.)

I have *heard* of hybrid threading models for C / C++, though I don't know about actual implementations.  Look for articles, etcetera that talk about Threads vs Fibres.

Answer (score 0):

> ...what's the use of Multithreading in this case?

Multithreading is older than multiprocessing. Multithreading is one model of *concurrent computing.* That is to say, it's a way to write a computer program in which different activities are allowed to happen independently from each other. A classic example is a multi-user network server that creates a new thread for each connected client. Each thread can talk to its own client in a simple, synchronous way even though there may be no synchrony between what the different clients want to do. You don't *need* to have multiple CPUs for that.

When multi-CPU computers were invented, using multiple threads to exploit them for parallel processing was a natural and obvious choice.

> I mean the computation time [for a green-threaded program that cannot exploit multiple CPUs] will still be the same.

That is true, but depending on what the different activities are that the program performs concurrently, the multi-threaded version of it may be easier to read and understand* than a program that's built around a different model of concurrency.

The reason is, we all were taught to write single-threaded, synchronous code when we were beginners. We understood that we were writing instructions that "the computer" would follow. We now say "a thread" instead of saying "the computer," but otherwise, the code executed by each thread can be mostly similar to the style of code that we wrote as beginners.

Part of what makes it so simple is, that the state of each of the concurrent activities can be mostly implicit in the contexts and the local variables (i.e., the stacks) of the different threads. If you choose a different model of concurrency (e.g., an [*event driven* model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture)) then you may have to *explicitly* represent more of that state with (maybe complex) data structures.

---

* Easier to *read* but not necessarily easier to *write* without making subtle mistakes. But, when I started working with large teams of software developers, they taught me that I'd be reading about ten lines of code for every one line that I wrote, so "easier to read but harder to write" turns out to be a win in the long run.

Comment: *Multithreading is older than multiprocessing* - Debatable.  Consider the CDC 6000 series architecture PPUs.  But you are probably correct for normal applications.  (PPUs were specialized I/O processors.)

Comment: Actually a bit more research and the Burroughs B5000 is possibly the earliest example of an SMP machine; circa 1961.   I guess it depends on what you mean by multiprocessing.

Comment: @StephenC, I guess my imagination was focused on of computers-as-commodity, not computers-as-capital-equipment when I answered. Or maybe it was a case of self-centered thinking (I learned about multithreading when writing code for small, single-CPU, embedded systems back in the 1980s.) Besides, I never should have said "multiprocessing" anyway because that covers any computer system in which different _processes_ can run concurrently regardless of whether or not the OS provides any threads-within-processes or, any support for communication between processes. Not sure what word to use instead.